# Wrong ORDS_PUBLIC_USER password ORDS 22.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-rest-data-services

I'm trying to install ORDS 22.1.1 on Oracle 19c db.

I get error:

> ```
> ORA-20202: ERROR: An error occurred during "ORDS_PUBLIC_USER" creation.  
> ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed  
> ORA-06512: at line 65
> ```

There is `INFO` that it occurs in `[*** script: ords_create_rest_users.sql]`.

There is a  `c_xxx constant varchar2(100) := to_char(****)`

This password doesn't pass the database password policy.

While I'm trying to install ORDS it didn't ask me for password for ORDS_PUBLIC_USER.
Furthemore I can't find the script ords_create_rest_users.sql (even after unziping ords.war) to check how he create the password.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, its strange that it doesnt ask for password for those users anymore and have no direct control over it. but the solution(or say workaround) is to disable the complex password verification temporarily while install and then enable it again.

1. Disable the password verification:

> ```
> SQL> alter profile default limit password_verify_function null;
> ```

2. Install ORDS.
3. Re-Enable the the password verification:

> ```
> SQL> alter profile default limit password_verify_function <verify_function_name>;
> ```

you can get  ***<verify_function_name>*** from below query for DEFAULT profile:

> ```
> SQL> select limit from dba_profiles where profile='DEFAULT' and resource_name='PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION';
> ```